# Finding the limit of $\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(3x)}$ for $x \to 0$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

As $x$ goes to $0$, what is the limit of
$$\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(3x)}$$

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: Got to $$(2-cos^2)/(1+3cos(x)-4cos(x)^3)$$

Comment: Ah, you have an error! The numerator should be $2 - \color{red}{2} \cos(x)^2$.

Comment: I concur, a typo, sorry about that. Won't let me edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting $x=2y,$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(3x)}$$

$$=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos4y}{1-\cos6y}$$

$$=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}\frac{2\sin^22y}{2\sin^23y} \text{ as }\cos2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$$

$$=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{4\cdot\left(\frac{\sin 2y}{2y}\right)^2}{9\cdot \left(\frac{\sin 3y}{3y}\right)^2}$$

$$=\frac49\text{ as  }\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}h=1$$

---

Alternatively,

$$\frac{1-\cos2x}{1-\cos3x}=\left(\frac{\sin2x}{\sin3x}\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac{1+\cos3x}{1+\cos2x}\right)$$

Now, $\lim_{x\to0}\cos ax=1$ for finite $a$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1+\cos3x}{1+\cos2x}\right)=\frac{1+1}{1+1}=1$$

and $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin2x}{\sin3x}\right)=\frac23\cdot \frac{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin2x}{2x}}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin3x}{3x}}=\frac23$$

Comment: Didn't get your transition from $$sin(2y)^2$$ Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Marshall, $1-\cos4y=2\sin^22y,$ right? Then to utilize the formula mentioned at the last line, I have divided the numerator & the denominator by $y^2$

Comment: Much obliged. Also forgive me as I my math abilities have yet to be honed.

Comment: @Marshall, please find the alternative approach, too. Please don't stop clearing confusion.

Answer (score 2):

One way to continue with your idea is to notice that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2-\color{red}2 cos(x)^2}{1+3cos(x)-4cos(x)^3} $$

is equal to

$$\lim_{y \to 1^-} \frac{2- \color{red}2  y^2}{1+3y-4y^3} $$

after making the change of variable $y = \cos x$. (With practice, you could learn to use the ideas this suggests *without* making the change of variable!)

(edit: red numerals to indicate corrections from the original expression)

Comment: Couldn't advance any further to be frank.

Comment: And if you aren't confident in / aren't allowed to make the change of variable... do it anyways in your scratch work to figure out what you need to do, then repeat the steps without making the change of variable!

Comment: Yes. Although I still don't get it. Everything I try to do gets me to 0.

Comment: What methods have you seen for dealing with limits of rational functions? Would another change of variable $z=y-1$ help so that you take a limit as $z$ approaches zero?

Comment: @Hurkyl There is an error in the numerator.  Should be $2 - 2y^2$ I believe.

Comment: @Hurkyl no, couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: (+1) for not giving the complete solution!

Answer (score 1):

Use the L'Hopital rule.
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(3x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{2\sin(2x)}{3\sin(3x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{4x}{9x}=\frac49$$

Comment: Not allowed(As in we weren't introduced to it) :(

Comment: If L'Hopital is not allowed..i think expansion is also not allowed...so you maybe use the definition of limit with an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof as you had know the answer??

Comment: I think he is supposed to solve it using the standard limits of sin(x)/x, cos(x)/x etc.

Comment: @Adam: Alas, while $(1-\cos(x))/x$ is standard, we would need the limit of $(1 - \cos(x)) / x^2$ here, and I'm not so sure *that* is standard.

Comment: @Xiaolang, $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x,$  right?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee yes,of course.

Comment: A simple way to see $(1-\cos x)/x^2$ without double angle formulas is to look at $(1-\cos x)(1 + \cos x)/x^2$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is expanding in Maclaurin series:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos 2x}{1- \cos 3x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-1 +\frac{4x^2}{2} - O(x^4)}{1- 1 + \frac{9x^2}{2} - O(x^4)} = \frac{\frac{4}{2}}{\frac{9}{2}}=\frac{4}{9}
$$

Comment: I'm sure your answer is great, tho I'm a noob and cannot really recognize what you did there. I'm supposed to do this the basic way.

Comment: 'Basic' is a vague definition. What I did I expanded both numerator and denominator trig functions in Maclaurin series, since both functions tend to 0 and wrote out the first two terms + the order of the rest of the terms that go to 0. Then I divide by $x^2$ to get constants and took limit. Hence the result.

Comment: Sadly, I have no idea what a Maclaurin series is.

Comment: It's just expansion around 0: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maclaurin%28cos%28x%29%29

Comment: If L'Hôspital's rule is not allowed, series expansion shouldn't be either.